# Gradle, Robolectric, and Espresso

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robolectric, android-espresso

Has anyone successfully gotten Robolectric and Espresso working (together) when building with Gradle (Android Studio)?

I've gotten Robolectric working in Android Studio due largely to Peter Friese's post http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/, but I'm unsure of how to integrate Espresso due to instrumentRunner/instrumentTest collisions.

Ideally I'd have a directory structure like the following:

```
 |--src
    └── main (application source - exists)
    └── test (Robolectric unit tests go here - exists)
    └── testEspresso [*new*] (espresso tests go here)
```

My Gradle+Android knowledge isn't very extensive, and I'm unsure of whether this is really a feasible thing (time, complexity, and fragility levels aren't too extreme) given the current state of Gradle+Android and if it is, how to go about doing so. Also in case it's of relevance, I have 2 different build flavors.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess by feasible I mean if the time, complexity, and fragility levels of the proposed solution aren't horrible. I updated my post to reflect this :)

Comment: @loeschg - Did you have any problems with robolectric seeing your resources? I have several build flavors too, and robolectric doesn't see my resources.

Comment: @PeterAjtai I found this article by Peter Friese to be really helpful. See if that helps you fix the problem. I also have a couple different build flavors. http://www.peterfriese.de/android-testing-with-robolectric/

Comment: @loescg thanks, yeah that's very helpful. i got it to work, but it looks like robolectric doesnt know about build flavors, so had to load a separate flavorless build config for the tests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a good example of Robolectric and Espresso working together in harmony, check out this sample project created by the Robolectric team:

https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle

Comment: I do not agree that the Deckard works in harmony. For me its not useable because of issues like https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/17 other templates works better like https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template or https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test

Comment: @nenick My answer is over 6 months old. A lot of things have changed since then. Thank you for providing better examples.

Comment: See fork for the same deckard-gradle, but with android-unit-test (robolectric and espresso are separated): git@github.com:almozavr/deckard-gradle.git

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which doesn't include any "hacks, Gradle plugins, IDE plugins, or IML editing" is http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/. Jake Wharton recommended this approach. With this, your Robolectric tests are in a separate Java module, separate from your main project. Espresso code lives with your main project.

Using JW's double-espresso (https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso) will simplify including Espresso and the dependency management madness that can come with it.

The solution @plackemacher mentioned, deckard-gradle, is still an option and is being maintained, though it does require some hacking/surgery to get working with the IDE.

<s>**Update**: See the discussion here regarding Robolectric and Gradle (relates to Gradle): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/xsOpEwtdTi4/discussion</s>

**Update**: While I have not used it, this looks to be the ticket. https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso.

---

For the time being, I elected to create a separate Espresso branch (git) which has the proper testRunner and test directory set. Not a horribly elegant solution... does require some vigilance to keep everything up-to-date, but it's working for now!

Will definitely change the answer should somebody find a better solution.

Comment: How does it behave in the long term? I'm afraid branching is a pretty bad idea for this sort of use case...

Comment: I am no longer working on the project for which this was done, so I can't really comment :P. See my updated answer.

Comment: @fstephany I'd definitely say do NOT make a separate branch like I suggested. There are more robust ways of doing this now. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks for the update. There's definitely a tooling issue here  but things seem to smoothen...